The conjugate of a cosine series is a sine series
In Katznelson's An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis the author defines the conjugate $\widetilde{S}$ of a trigonometric series
$$S \sim \sum_{n = \infty}^\infty a_n e^{inx}$$
by
$$\widetilde{S} \sim \sum_{n = \infty}^\infty -i \operatorname{sgn}(n) \ a_n e^{inx}.$$
Exercise 1.3. asks to formally check that if $S \sim \sum a_j \cos{jx}$ then $\widetilde{S} \sim \sum a_j \sin{jx}$.
My attempt.
Using Euler's formula, we may formally write
\begin{align}
S \sim \sum_{j = -\infty}^\infty a_j \cos{jt}
= \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum a_j e^{ijt} + \sum a_{-j} e^{ijt}\right)
= \sum \frac{a_j + a_{-j}}{2} e^{ijt}.
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
    \widetilde{S} &\sim \sum_{j = -\infty}^\infty  \operatorname{sgn}{j} \frac{a_j + a_{-j}}{2i} e^{ijt} \\
    &= \frac{1}{2i} \left(\sum \operatorname{sgn}(j) a_{j} e^{ijt} + \sum \operatorname{sgn}(j) a_{-j} e^{ijt}\right) \\
    &= \sum a_j \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(j) e^{ijt} + \operatorname{sgn}(-j) e^{-ijt}}{2i}\\
    &= \sum_{j = -\infty}^{-1} a_{j} \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(j) e^{ijt} + \operatorname{sgn}(-j) e^{-ijt}}{2i} + \sum_{j = 1}^\infty a_j \frac{e^{ijt} - e^{-ijt}}{2i} \\
&= \sum_{j = -\infty}^{-1} a_{j} \sin{(-jt)}+ \sum_{j = 1}^\infty a_j \sin{jt}
\end{align}
I'm not sure how to conclude from here. Is this even correct?

I think what you wrote is correct.
In the following, I'm going to prove the following two claims :
Claim 1 : If $S \sim \displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} a_j \cos jt$, then $\widetilde{S} \sim\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\color{red}{\operatorname{sgn}(j)}a_j\sin jt$.
Claim 2 : If $S \sim \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j \cos{jt}$, then $\widetilde{S} \sim \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j \sin{jt}$.

Claim 1 : If $S \sim \displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} a_j \cos{jt}$, then $\widetilde{S} \sim\displaystyle\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\color{red}{\operatorname{sgn}(j)}a_j\sin jt$.
Proof :
As you wrote, we have
$$\begin{align}S&\sim \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} a_j \cos{jt}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} a_j\cdot \frac 12(e^{ijt} +  e^{-ijt})
\\\\&= \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{a_j+a_{-j}}2 e^{ijt}\end{align}$$
So, we have
$$\begin{align}\widetilde{S}&\sim \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}(-i)\operatorname{sgn}(j)\frac{a_j+a_{-j}}2 e^{ijt}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(j)\frac{a_j+a_{-j}}{2i} e^{ijt}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{2i}\operatorname{sgn}(j)a_je^{ijt}+\frac{1}{2i}\operatorname{sgn}(-j)a_{j}e^{-ijt}\bigg)
\\\\&=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{2i}\operatorname{sgn}(j)a_je^{ijt}-\frac{1}{2i}\operatorname{sgn}(j)a_{j}e^{-ijt}\bigg)
\\\\&=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(j)a_j\cdot\frac{e^{ijt}-e^{-ijt}}{2i}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(j)a_j\sin jt\end{align}$$

Claim 2 : If $S \sim \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j \cos{jt}$, then $\widetilde{S} \sim \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j \sin{jt}$.
Proof :
$$\begin{align}S&\sim \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j \cos{jt}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j\cdot \frac 12(e^{ijt} +  e^{-ijt})
\\\\&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_j}{2}e^{ijt}+\sum_{j=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{a_{-j}}{2}e^{ijt}\end{align}$$
So, we have
$$\begin{align}\widetilde{S}&\sim \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-i)\operatorname{sgn}(j)\frac{a_j}{2}e^{ijt}+\sum_{j=-\infty}^{-1}(-i)\operatorname{sgn}(j)\frac{a_{-j}}{2}e^{ijt}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(j)\frac{a_j}{2i}e^{ijt}+\sum_{j=-\infty}^{-1}\operatorname{sgn}(j)\frac{a_{-j}}{2i}e^{ijt}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(j)\frac{a_j}{2i}e^{ijt}+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(-j)\frac{a_{j}}{2i}e^{-ijt}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(j)\frac{a_j}{2i}e^{ijt}-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(j)\frac{a_{j}}{2i}e^{-ijt}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(j)a_j\cdot \frac{e^{ijt}-e^{-ijt}}{2i}
\\\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j\sin jt\end{align}$$

Comments :
The exercise 1.2. has $\frac{A_0}{2}+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n\cos nt+B_n\sin nt)$. So, I guess that the exercise 1.3. also deals with the case where the sum $\displaystyle\sum$ represents $\displaystyle\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}$, not $\displaystyle\sum_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}$.

By linearity of conjugation, it is enough to check on one term:
$\begin{align}
\widetilde{\cos nt}&=\widetilde{\frac{e^{nti}+e^{-nti}}{2}}\\
&=\frac12(\widetilde{e^{nti}}+\widetilde{e^{-nti}})\\
&=\frac12(-i\operatorname{sgn}(n)e^{nti}-i\operatorname{sgn}(-n)e^{-nti})\\
&=\frac1{2i}(\operatorname{sgn}(n)e^{nti}+\operatorname{sgn}(-n)e^{-nti})\\
&=\frac1{2i}(\operatorname{sgn}(n)e^{nti}-\operatorname{sgn}(n)e^{-nti})\\
&=\operatorname{sgn}(n)\frac{e^{nti}-e^{-nti}}{2i}\\
&=\operatorname{sgn}(n)\sin nt
\end{align}
$
